# How do you say you are a nosey person in Korean?

Tags: spoken-korean

How do you say you are a nosey person in Korean?

Answer (score 5):

Nosy means '참견하기 좋아하는' in dictionary. So, a nosy person can be translated into '참견쟁이' because -쟁이 is a suffix which has the meaning 'someone who does or prefers something' (e.g. 개구쟁이, 그림쟁이, 이발쟁이)

Or, an idiom '오지랖이 넓다' also means 'being nosy'. So if you describe someone with this idiom, then it means that person is a quite nosy one. There is also a slang '오지라퍼'(오지랖 + -er) that means a nosy person.

- 그 남자는 오지랖이 넓은 사람이야. = He is a nosy person.
- 그 여자애는 완전 오지라퍼야! = She's nosy as hell!